# sed - append to next line using command line

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, append

I wish to append " dddd" to the next line whenever I encounter "=" in a textfile.

This command

`sed -i '/=/s|$| dddd|' *.krn`

is close to what I am looking for as it appends to the current line where "=" is. How can I append to the next line instead?

Comment: give some input/output sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use append, see here:

- http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-40

E.g.:

```
$ echo $'abc\ndef\ne=f\nqqq'
abc
def
e=f
qqq
$ echo $'abc\ndef\ne=f\nqqq'|sed '/=/adddd'
abc
def
e=f
dddd
qqq
```

Edited to clarify as per comment from @je4d- if you want to append to what is present in the next line, you can use this:

```
$ echo $'abc\ndef\ne=f\nqqq\nyyy'
abc
def
e=f
qqq
yyy
$ echo $'abc\ndef\ne=f\nqqq\nyyy'|sed '/=/{n;s/$/ dddd/}'
abc
def
e=f
qqq dddd
yyy
```

See here for a great sed cheatsheet for more info if you want:

- http://www.catonmat.net/download/sed.stream.editor.cheat.sheet.txt

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wanted, it adds a line after the match rather than appending to the line after the match

Comment: Thanks for clarification @je4d! Edited to clarify for this case.

Comment: Yes. If you have a solution for adding it to the next line that already exists that would be great as I can't really use this..

Comment: @Michael - just added that after je4d pointed that out, sorry for misunderstanding what you wanted.

Comment: Yes thanks! But I cannot perform this command as it just hangs and nothing happens. `sed '/=/{n;s/$/ dddd/}'` Perhaps because I use cygwin?

Comment: Works I think..! I forgot *.krn

Comment: Should work fine in Cygwin. Did you want to specify a file (i.e. `sed '/=/{n;s/$/ dddd/}' somefile`)? Can you copy the whole thing I put above (i.e. `echo $'abc\ndef\ne=f\nqqq\nyyy'|sed '/=/{n;s/$/ dddd/}'`) and confirm that works?

Answer (score 3):

So to reiterate the question, when you match on one line, you want to append a string to the next line---a line that already exists, rather than adding a new line after it with the new data.

I think this will work for you:

```
sed '/=/ { N; s/$/ ddd/ }'
```

Say you have a file like:

```
=
hello
world
=
foo
bar
=
```

Then processing this command on it will yield:

```
=
hello ddd
world
=
foo ddd
bar
=
```

The trick here is using the `N` command first. This reads in the "next" line of input. Commands following it will be applied to the next line.

Comment: @MichaelWard, did you pass it the `-i` flag and the `*.krn` files like you did in the original post? This was a more general answer without that. Try it with `sed -i '/=/ { N; s/$/ ddd/ }' *.krn`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a sed guru, but I can do what you want with awk:

```
'{PREV=MATCH; MATCH="no"}
 /=/{MATCH="yes"} 
 PREV=="yes"{print $0 " dddd"}
 PREV!="yes"{print}'
```

Demo:

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nba=r\nfoo\n=bar\nfoo\nfoo\nb=ar\nx' 
foo
ba=r
foo
=bar
foo
foo
b=ar
x

$ echo -e 'foo\nba=r\nfoo\n=bar\nfoo\nfoo\nb=ar\nx' | awk '{APPEND=LAST; LAST="no"} /=/{LAST="yes"} APPEND=="yes"{print $0 " dddd"} APPEND!="yes"{print}'
foo
ba=r
foo dddd
=bar
foo dddd
foo
b=ar
x dddd
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "=\nx " | sed '/=/{$q;N;s/$/dddd/}'
=
x dddd
```